# Java Nats Client: Incomprehensible error message "Subject remapping requires Options.oldRequestStyle() ..."

Tags: nats.io

In our project we have used NATS (**Server-Version 2.1.9**) as our message server.
Often we got some error logs in **Java Nats Client** like:

```
`ERROR: Subject remapping requires Options.oldRequestStyle() to be set on the Connection`
```

It comes from io.nats.jnats version 2.8 (nats.client.impl.NatsConnection # deliverReply).

But we don't notice any problem in our system.

So my question is: How can it happen, what does it warn us about, and how can we handle it?

Comment: I've digged a little. Sorry, no answer yet, but it might help others looking for an answer to know that the error message was introduced with the "Subject Remapping Fix" https://github.com/nats-io/nats.java/pull/327.

Comment: Also, this is the only use of System.out in the Java NATS client except for the connection tracing that can be enabled as option, see io.nats.client.Options#isTraceConnection. Might indicate that there is still room for improvement there...

Comment: https://github.com/nats-io/nats.java/issues/424 Incomprehensible stdout message “ERROR: Subject remapping requires Options.oldRequestStyle() …”

Comment: Anyone seen this error reappear in version 2.10.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the response to our github issue that addresses this: https://github.com/nats-io/nats.java/issues/424

In short, this is fixed in our 2.9.0 version. I answered in the issue:

We are able to reproduce this under those conditions of re-using messages. I had also seen it intermittently but couldn't quite put my finger on it.
As it turns out, the error message is a misleading anyway. It happens when we can't match the incoming message with the outgoing one / future that made the request. This should actually never happen. Since it was out-of-band (async) there really wasn't much we could do so printing a messages was better than nothing.
The good news is the current 2.9.0-SNAPSHOT has a fix regarding message handling that addresses this problem. Can you try upgrading to 2.9.0-SNAPSHOT and see if this fixes your problem? 2.9.0-SNAPSHOT is stable and backward compatible since it is almost exclusive JetStream additions and improvements.

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution. We don't have got this error message any more since 2.9.0-SNAPSHOT.